# What font is used in the images on the Temtem kickstarter page?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I tried using Identifont but it gave me some wildly different [results](http://www.identifont.com/identify?17+.+10+5P+2E+4A+1KT+2L+6XA+1U7+2U+53K+1KK+1A+1LA+1QZ+7G+9Z). Here's what the font looks like.

[image: Temtem type chart]

The [Temtem kickstarter page](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/cremagames/temtem-massively-multiplayer-creature-collection-a) has more images with this font.

Comment: Why don't you simply ask them?

Comment: I feel silly for not thinking of that before. Thank you. If I get a reply then I'll add an answer to my question.